# IPhone OAuth Tutorial?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oauth

Is there any tutorial out there showing how to use OAuth on IPhone? Basically all of the tutorials are for twitter, i need something which work for any website, which has OAuth and give general view how to make it work on IPhone.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following link has answered to my question.

http://davidquail.com/2009/12/07/oauth-authorization-callback-on-the-iphone-with-webview/

Comment: Hello, can you please share your code with us?

Answer (score 3):

http://oauth.net/code/ has supporting code, etc.

A tutorial is here http://matrixpointer.com/karl/posts/mpoauth-on-the-iphone-mpoauthmobile

Here http://github.com/jaanus/PlainOAuth

Comment: I have tried this code but its not working for me :(

Answer (score 3):

Was just doing some research on this as well, primarily for Facebook OAuth, but you might find it useful:

http://www.alohacocoa.com/post/647589940/oauth-and-facebook-iphone-sdk