# How to upgrade from Twitter BasicAuth to Oauth in my iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth

I have struck with posting my application to apple because of following reason.

Application is not posting tweets to twitter. I have implemmented twitter with basic Auth. so that it is not working from August 31, 2010.

So can any one help me

How to upgrade from Twitter BasicAuth to Oauth in my iPhone Application.

Another question is:

This (Oauth) should not change the UI of my application. means when user clicks on twitter button it should ask user name and password every time, and if we click on send button it should send tweets to twitter.

i implemented the Oauth but it is asking the username and password one time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending tweets from iPhone apps using Oauth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954236/sending-tweets-from-iphone-apps-using-oauth)

Comment: See also [IPhone OAuth Tutorial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901511/iphone-oauth-tutorial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you check out [MGTwitterEngine](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) on GitHub. This library wraps up the Twitter API nicely and does the OAuth stuff as well.

You don't need to ask you user for their username and password every time.  You can get their credentials initially and then store the access token you get back from Twitter (or from MGTwitterEngine if you choose to use that library) and use that for next time.

MGTwitterEngine wraps up the access token with an *OAToken* object which does the persistence for you.

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/ is a drop-in OAuth implementation for iOS and Mac OS X